# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dependency1Provider <- dependency1 <- $http <- $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

After copying some example code form angularjs' website I've received the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dependency1Provider <- dependency1 <- $http <- $compile
```

This was after I've failed to get the $httpProvider because it has to be used in the configuration stage on angularjs (before everything else, in config(..)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the damned code I copied without much thinking:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
     'request': function(config) {
         // same as above
      },

      'response': function(response) {
         // same as above
      }
    };
  });
```

The problem (obviously) was that the function inside the push had 2 example parameters - "dependency1, dependency2", after removing them everything was working again.

Hope this could help someone as tired as me trying to search for that error message instead of reading it.

Comment: ooooh thank you! I have spent an hour for this problem!